# Shouldn't the API help be consistent with the trademark guidance?

Tags: bug, status-completed

The description for the two StackAuth Routes within the [API help](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/help) both contain the phrase **StackExchange network** - shouldn't this rather be **Stack Exchange Network** to be consistent with the recently published [trademark guidance](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance), see section *Proper Use of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Name*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many men died to bring you trademark compliance.

[Updated `/help`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/help).

Comment: Many more died trying to raise this issue.

Comment: How many Bothans died?

Answer (score -1):

Given that the publisher of the API is also the owner of the trademark, I'd say they're free to represent it varyingly at their discretion.  Also consider that the documentation in question isn't exactly general-release.

Comment: While the former is true I think they would do themselves and us a favor to lead by example, there has been enough confusion regarding topics like this already. The [trademark guidance](http://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance) has been a very welcome major step forward in this regard and is very clear and helpful, IMHO.

Comment: Regarding the latter: that's why I filed the bug here, to help improving the documentation on the long run ;) Maybe my attempt to phrase even bug reports and feature requests as a question is getting a bit overboard here and there in that it might look like I'd really wonder why this is the case, while elsewhere I would have simply filed a bug *The API help is inconsistent with the trademark guidance.* ...

Comment: I don't know about the US but when we received a trademark in Australia our legal team insisted that we spell it exactly the same, everywhere, and every time, suffix it with a &trade; or else there may be grounds that we're not using our trademark. Now our legal team were incredibly anal and they registered the trademark as ALL CAPS which was incredibly annoying (reading a sentence such as "at OUR PRODUCT we value blah blah OUR PRODUCT blah blah OUR PRODUCT") but I'm assuming they made us do it for a reason....

Comment: I like STACKOVERFLOW.